# jQuery tree menu - parent categories not being displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tree

I'm trying to create a tree structure using plain HTML and jQuery. I made it so far, but I have a small issue: I don't understand why the `<li>` elements that have children are not displayed, but if you click on the bullet or in the place where the name should be, the children are being displayed and also the parent category.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('li')
                .css('pointer','default')
            $('li:has(ul)')
                .click(function(event){
                    if (this == event.target) {                     
                        $(this).children().toggle('slow');
                    }
                    return false;
                })              
                .children().hide();
            $('li:not(:has(ul))').css({cursor:'default'});
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Aliquam ultricies neque vel efficitur luctus.
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Aenean quis sapien ultrices, convallis mauris ut, vestibulum dolor.</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    Aliquam ac lectus vehicula, imperdiet orci a, gravida dolor.
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Donec eu sapien eu ante euismod elementum.</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Donec eu urna non nulla dapibus porttitor.
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Nulla dignissim felis eu risus posuere, ac venenatis nunc sagittis.</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Fusce ac nibh facilisis, iaculis velit vestibulum, scelerisque diam.</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </a></li>
            </ul>
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cras ornare libero in massa lobortis bibendum.</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I also created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0nf8r6jb/).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with the jQuery's children function. If you call this function without parameter it will apply the changes all of the children elements. In this case that is the problem because the `<a>` tag which has the text content is a children element of a `<li>` so you should use the children function with a parameter like this `.children("ul")`. The full working example you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kow62nmd/).

Comment: Yep! Adding that fixed the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Any ideea about how could I enable the same behaviour when the user is clicking the a href?

Comment: I think you should remove the "a" tags and it will works like a charm. I updated the fiddle you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/kow62nmd/1/